# Integrate WCF with ADFS 2.0 and ACS - Some guide needed

Tags: .net, wcf, saml, adfs, acs

We are planning to provide single sign on to our set off .NET applications(Web and windows) using ADFS 2.0, ACS and WIF. I am quite new to these technologies.

I have seen quite few videos on channel 9, most of them are giving SSO using google, yahoo facebook. Would appreciate if you can provide step by step process to configure ADFS with ACS.

Is it possible to call ADFS and ACS from WCF? We are planning to have WCF which will collaborate with ADFS and ACS and issue SAML to token to our set of applications. 
So it’s like our application will call WCF for authentication with required credential, WCF will then call ADFS to get IdPToken, that IdpToken will then send to ACS to get SAML token, and returned SAML token will then forwarded to application. I tried to search set of examples for this but could not find. Some guidance or link will be useful.

Also it required to ADFS available to internet? Do we have to expose it to public domain?

Answer (score 3):

There's an excellent ACS - WIF guide over on the Technet Wiki [Windows Identity Foundation (WIF) and Azure AppFabric Access Control Service (ACS) Content Map](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1546.aspx).

[MSDN ACS 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/gg429786.aspx)

[ACS 2.0 Samples and Documentation](http://acs.codeplex.com/). This has ACS / WCF samples

[Identity Developer Training Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=14347) This has ADFS / WCF samples.

If you want external users to authenticate using ADFS then yes it has to be available to the Internet. However, you can install an ADFS Proxy Server in the DMZ and then put the real instance of ADFS behind a firewall.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into it. I also found interesting one here:http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willpe/archive/2010/10/25/windows-authentication-adfs-and-the-access-control-service.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You might find step by step guides in white papers (en anglais == In English) from http://www.microsoft.com/france/interop/ressources/documents.aspx
In particular, I think of Step-by-Step Guide: Federated Collaboration with Shibboleth 2.0 and SharePoint 2010 technologies Livre blanc « Guide étape-par-étape Collaboration fédérée avec Shibboleth 2.0 et SharePoint 2010 » (en anglais)

For ACS, you might want to go to Wade Wegner's (www.wadewegner.com) blog or Vittorio Bertocci's blog (blogs.msdn.com/b/vbertocci/)
I also have a few posts at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/benjguin/archive/tags/identityfederation/

regards